# Is it bad practice to place an if/else inside of another else?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

```
if() {

}else {
    if (IsAlternateRow=='true')
        IsAlternateRow = 'false';
    else
        IsAlternateRow = 'true';
}
```

Can I place an if and else statement inside of another else statement?

Comment: Try to post this question to the code review website (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It's more suited there.

Comment: yes, technically speaking you can do this, but you will want to avoid it whenever possible to keep your code 'clean' and readable

Comment: Sidenote: `if (IsAlternateRow == 'true')` will certainly be false, as `==` evaluates object reference equality. If you wanted string comparison, use `.equals()`.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this as Java? The code you posted isn't valid Java, even ignoring the empty parenthesis.

Comment: Well it's not longer Java but JavaScript,... which makes for a lot of confusion :D

Comment: Yeah, this question has significantly changed since it was created. First it was a "how can I change this code to make it better" and was tagged `java`. Now it's a "can I nest if/else statements" tagged `javascript` ...

Comment: @editors/approvers - At least make an attempt to fix the spelling errors in the title while you're at it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
IsAlternateRow = !IsAlternateRow;
```

(updated to show what this would look like in your code)

```
var IsAlternateRow = false;

if(/* -- insert equation here -- */) 
{
 // do something
} 
 else 
{
    IsAlternateRow = !IsAlternateRow;
}
```

Comment: it's a simple way to invert a boolean value.
`IsAlternateRow` (interpret as false) ` = !IsAlternateRow `(interpret as !false, or true)
This works from false to true and from true to false.

Comment: @theJava: `IsAlternateRow` will `===` the opposite of what `IsAlternateRow` currently equals, in terms of Booleans.

Comment: I am just confused... can you place this code in my statement and show me... should i declare isAlternateRow somewhere

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you would implement it in this scenario.

Comment: should i place IsAlternateRow=='true' in my if condition

Comment: if you put a boolean in IsAlternateRow, it will contain the boolean values TRUE or FALSE, instead of the strings 'true' and 'false'. this will make it a lot easier to compare the value of IsAlternateRow.

for example : 
`if(IsAlternateRow) { //do things `

Answer (score 10):

Yes, placing an `if` inside an `else` is perfectly acceptable practice but in most cases use of `else if` is clearer and cleaner.  E.g.

```
if (test) {
   // Do something
} else if (otherTest) {
   // Do something else
} else {
   // Do a third thing
}
```

infact this is short-hand for

```
if (test) {
   // Do something
} else {
     if (otherTest) {
         // Do something else
     } else {
         // Do a third thing
     }
}
```

and the two should compile to almost identical programs in most situations.

Your code example is not very clear and will not compile correctly, clearer sample code may help us to help you out.

Answer (score 9):

**Note: the question got re-tagged as JavaScript after this answer was posted (it was originally about Java, so this answer is about Java).**

In general, it is fine to place an `if` and an `else` inside an `else` clause.

There are, however, several issues with your code. `IsAlternateRow=='true'` isn't syntactically valid.

- If it's a string comparison, you should use double quotes and `.equals()`;
- If it's a boolean comparison, you're better off simply doing `IsAlternateRow = !IsAlternateRow` instead of the entire nested `if`.

Comment: @Chris Nope. 'true' and 'false' are not valid character constants.

Comment: @Isaac Truett - I upvoted your comment, but the question has changed tags from `java` to `javascript`, so it no longer applies. We all got pwned by late editing :(

Comment: @Issac Why aren't 'true' and 'false' valid character constants.

Comment: @Ash In Java, single quotes wrap **single** character constants. Multiple characters are Strings, and String constants are wrapped in double quotes. `"foo"` is a valid String constant. `'foo'` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 4):

return (IsAlternateRow.equals('true')) ? 'false' : 'true'

Answer (score 3):

In general, I'd say that to answer questions like this, you should ask yourself,

> Is this easy to read?

Shallow-nested `if/else` statements aren't terrible, but once you start nesting ad nauseum, you should probably refactor.

Answer (score 2):

This is fine, but there are easier ways to do what you are doing:

```
IsAlternateRow = !IsAlternateRow
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. If you want to evaluate the same object/variable several time you could use a switch statement but in many case staggered if statement will do the job just as well.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, you can infinitely nest if/else statements.  The code you supplied will compile no problem.  Although given that you're talking about Java, I imagine unless that's pseudo code, it isn't going to provide the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to do it:

```
if() {

} else if (IsAlternateRow=='true') {
    IsAlternateRow = 'false';
}
 else
{
    IsAlternateRow = 'true';
}
```

Comment: using a string for boolean comparisons like this isn't the best way though.